# multiple lines in cell for text label in a list view

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a title and detail text for a cell in the list view but I can only get one line of text.

Here is how I'm populating the cell.

```
cell.textLabel.text = rowName as String
```

but I'd like to get it to look like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to what you have done so far, you can set the text for the detail label:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = "Hello"
```